# Tool which can be integrated with NUnit to control database transactions

Tags: open-source, database, c#, software-testing, unit-tests

We are using `Selenium` for UI testing with `NUnit` and having so much issues with `DataBase` state handling. However, we now want to do a database clean up, insert some data into `x` number of tables and rollback the transaction after the test run. I did some research and found [NDbUnit](https://github.com/NDbUnit/NDbUnit/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) but never used anything like that in past. Anyone fall into the same trap and what's the way out?

**Any tool that can be easily integrated with NUnit to handle such database transactions?**